# Best Way to insert multiple records in Database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I just came across a situation where i had to insert multiple records into the database. The records i had were in generic list and now i have found two ways to insert multiple records.

1. i just do it as usual using ExecuteNonQuery and i use foreach loop to insert every records one by one(i don't think that this is the best way to do it since this  way makes multiple trips to the database to insert the record).

   ```
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()
       {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection()
        {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
           cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employees(id, name) VALUES 
            (@id,@name);";
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", entry.Id);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", entry.Name);
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
       }
        }
   ```
2. i tried using SqlBulkCopy class i converted the Generic List to DataTable and used SqlBulkCopy.

   ```
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
       {
           using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
           {

               sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Employees";
               con.Open();
               sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
               con.Close();
           }
       }
   ```

Both the methods do the intended work. But i want to know which is the best way. If there are any other better way to do this i am open to suggesstions.

Comment: Bulk copy is the fastest by far, but it will fail the whole batch if an error occurs. Using plain SQL (first choice) will give you a lot more flexibility when the operation becomes ugly and will fire triggers (if any) **on each insert**, which is an overhead compared to a set-based insert and also if you are using transactions.

Comment: I'd highly recommend considering using an ORM (like Entity or NHibernate), specially if you plan to handle many different tables on C# with updates, inserts or deletes. They might not be the fastest (although fast enough), but it will be a lot easier to handle data in C#.

Comment: Actually i have 4 tables for which i have to insert bulk data. Entity might do the job i think. It never crossed my mind. Thanks a ton.

Comment: And don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @SMor Did not know the evil behind addwithvalue, 'command.Parameters.Add()' should be good then!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Table-Valued Parameters (TVPs) ,which were introduced in SQL Server 2008. Before SQL Server 2008, it was not possible to pass a table variable in stored procedure as a parameter, after SQL Server now we can pass Table-Valued Parameter to send multiple rows of data to a stored procedure or a function without creating a temporary table or passing so many parameters. have a look at below example

```
CREATE TYPE UT_Employee AS TABLE  
(  
Emp_Id int NOT NULL,  
EmployeeName nvarchar(MAX),  
EmpSalary varchar(50),  
StateId varchar(50),  
CityId varchar(50)  
)  

CREATE PROCEDURE USP_Insert_Employee_Info
(
  @Employee_Details [UT_Employee] READONLY
)  
AS  
BEGIN  

INSERT INTO dbo.Employee  
(  
Emp_Id,  
EmployeeName,  
EmpSalary,  
StateId,  
CityId  
)  
SELECT * FROM @Employee_Details  
END
```

Inserting multiple values into stored procedure as below

```
DECLARE @Employee_Details AS UT_Employee
INSERT INTO @Employee_Details 
SELECT 1001,'Abcd',10000,101,21 UNION ALL
SELECT 1002,'dggg',20000,121,15 UNION ALL
SELECT 1003,'esse',22222,122,35 UNION ALL
SELECT 1004,'uyyy',44333,121,32 UNION ALL
SELECT 1005,'dghd',13233,656,87 

EXEC dbo.USP_Insert_Employee_Info @Employee_Details = @Employee_Details
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd normally use a Table-Valued Parameter for this. The explanation of how to do that is a bit long to put here, but check out [Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) on Microsoft Docs for how to do this.

Comment: This is helpfull!!

Comment: Thanks for sharing.